# Add new field for Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have a dict which I have used `Counter` to get term frequencies for each key e.g. `'A'` and `'B'`.

```
dict = {'A': Counter({'food': 30, 'menu': 19, 'good': 15}), 'B': Counter({'one': 5, 'chicken': 10})}
```

I would like to be able to add a new field so that each term has another value.

I have tried:

```
for key, values in dict.items():
    for it1, it2 in values:
         dict[key][it1][it2] = 0
```

but I receive:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Do I need to remove the Counter object? How do I create a new value and how do I access this value?

Comment: `for it1, it2 in values.items():`

Comment: The value of `values` is _one_ counter. You cannot split it into `it1` and `it2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off creating an entirely new dictionary, to have that extra nested dict:

```
dct = {key: {k: {v: 0} for k, v in values.items()} for key, values in dct.items()}
```

Comment: but then you lose the `Counter` capability.

Comment: forget that. I realized that I don't understand the question. Time to go to bed :)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted - thank you. Sorry to other answerers for not phrasing my question more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question. You want to add one more item to the counter?. If that is the case, you could do by updating the counter object. the count will increase as you keep on updating it.

```
mydict = {'A': Counter({'food': 30, 'menu': 19, 'good': 15}), 'B': Counter({'one': 5, 'chicken': 10})}
mydict['A'].update(['price'])
mydict['B'].update(['cow'])
print mydict

{'A': Counter({'food': 30, 'menu': 19, 'good': 15, 'price': 1}), 'B': Counter({'chicken': 10, 'one': 5, 'cow': 1})}
```

if you do update again

```
mydict['A'].update(['price'])
mydict['B'].update(['cow'])
print mydict
```

will result in

```
{'A': Counter({'food': 30, 'menu': 19, 'good': 15, 'price': 2}), 'B': Counter({'chicken': 10, 'one': 5, 'cow': 2})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without creating a new `dict` you can manipulate your current `dict` with `Counter` inside.

You can print your current items like this way:

```
dct = {'A': Counter({'food': 30, 'menu': 19, 'good': 15}), 'B': Counter({'one': 5, 'chicken': 10})}

for k, v in dct.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Output:

```
>>> A Counter({'food': 30, 'menu': 19, 'good': 15})
>>> B Counter({'chicken': 10, 'one': 5})
```

In order to modify values inside `Counter dict`, you can do something like this:

```
for k, v in dct:
    if "food" in v:
        v["food"] = 666
```

Output:

```
print(dct)

>>> {'A': Counter({'food': 666, 'menu': 19, 'good': 15}), 'B': Counter({'chicken': 10, 'one': 5})}
```

And if you want to add new elements to your `Counter dict` you can do something like this:

```
for k, v in dct.items():
    if "food" in v:
        v.update({"new_food":0})

print(dct)
```

Output:

```
>>> {'A': Counter({'food': 30, 'menu': 19, 'good': 15, 'new_food': 0}), 'B': Counter({'chicken': 10, 'one': 5})}
```

Otherwise if you want to have a new `"regular"` `dict` you can use `dict comprehension`:

```
new_dct = {k:{key:val for key,val in v.items()} for k,v in dct.items()}

print(new_dct)

>>> {'A': {'food': 30, 'menu': 19, 'good': 15}, 'B': {'chicken': 10, 'one': 5}}
```